# Import HERE Maps Premium SDK to Swift Cocoa touch project

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa

currently I am importing the Here Maps Premium SDK to the swift 3 project with cocoa touch framework.

According to the developers' guide of the Here Maps Starter SDK, we should use bridging header to To import the SDK to swift. So how about the project with framework?

Is there anyone use modulemap to import the SDK successfully?

Comment: yes. I guess it's not working for you ? What are your concrete problems ?Can you share your modulemap ?